# Sort a structure which consists of two arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have a structure which looks like this:

```
struct MyStruct {
    int a[9];
    int index[9];
}
```

I wish to sort this structure according to the values of the array 'a' and have the corresponding values of array 'index' automatically adjust to the same.

Kindly guide me as to how should I write the compare function for such a structure.

**EDIT:** I want to sort such a structure using inbuilt sort functions like `qsort` or `sort` by passing this structure and using a custom compare function to sort the structure according to values of array 'a'. This would help me to learn how to use such compare functions hence the specific request.

Comment: I have edited the question. Sorry for the missing tags

Comment: C or C++? Pick one and only one.

Comment: Either of the language could work and structures are applicable in both languages. So a person proficient in EITHER of those languages would be able to answer such a question. Anyhow I have edited the question again to remove C but it would be helpful if you can explain why something similar was necessary.

Comment: Using `std::sort` seems like a good idea. Now you just have to write a function `bool compare(const MyStruct& left, const MyStruct& right)` that tells if `left` is less than `right`, or not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [`sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) uses [`swap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/swap/) to rearrange the order and swap gets addresses to swap that points to the data used for sorting ie. `a` of type `int&`.

So here is a solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
static_assert(__cplusplus >= 201103L, "not C++11");
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class OhMy {
public:
    int a[9];
    int index[9];
    OhMy() {
        int i = 9;
        for (int& b : a)
            b = i--;
        i = 19;
        for (int& b : index)
            b = i--;
    }
    template <class T>
    void swap(T& i,T& j) {
        std::swap(i,j);
        // dirty pointer arithmetic
        std::swap(index[std::distance(&a[0],&i)],index[std::distance(&a[0],&j)]);
    }

    void sort() {
        std::sort(std::begin(a),std::end(a));
    }

    void dump() {
        copy(std::begin(a),std::end(a), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
        cout << endl;
        copy(std::begin(index),std::end(index), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
        cout << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    OhMy ohMy;

    cout << "Before:";
    ohMy.dump();
    cout << "swap:";
    ohMy.swap(ohMy.a[0],ohMy.a[1]);
    ohMy.dump();
    cout << "After sort:";
    ohMy.sort();
    ohMy.dump();

    return 0;
}
```

And it works! ***NOT!!!***

> Before:9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
>   19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11
>   swap:8 9 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
>   18 19 17 16 15 14 13 12 11
>   After sort:1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>   18 19 17 16 15 14 13 12 11

So `sort` uses `std::swap` or `std::swap_iter` instead of a local visible `swap`.

You will have to make your own sort as all the sorts known to me only take a `cmp` and not a `swap` as arguments.